# Concatenate iterators in Groovy

Tags: groovy, iterator

Given three iterators

```
it1, it2, it3
```

how can I return one iterator that iterates over it1, then over it2 and last it3?

Lets say

```
def it1 = [1, 2].iterator()
def it2 = [3, 4].iterator()
def it3 = [5, 6].iterator()
```

I want to have an iterator that will return

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: IIRC there's nothing built-in, [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat%28java.util.Iterator,%20java.util.Iterator%29) and [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/IteratorChain.html)  both have utility classes for doing this, though, or you can write your own in a 10-ish lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such iterator that I know of in Groovy, but you could write your own:

```
class SequentialIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    List iterators
    int index = 0
    boolean done = false
    T next

    SequentialIterator( Iterator<T> ...iterators ) {
        this.iterators = iterators
        loadNext()
    }

    private void loadNext() {
        while( index < iterators.size() ) {
            if( iterators[ index ].hasNext() ) {
                next = iterators[ index ].next()
                break
            }
            else {
                index++
            }
        }
        if( index >= iterators.size() ) {
            done = true
        }
    }

    void remove() {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    boolean hasNext() {
        !done
    }

    T next() {
        if( done ) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException()
        }
        T ret = next
        loadNext()
        ret
    }
}

def it1 = [1, 2].iterator()
def it2 = [3, 4].iterator()
def it3 = [5, 6].iterator()

assert new SequentialIterator( it1, it2, it3 ).collect() == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Or, if you're feeling greedy (and will need all the data loaded at the same time) you could just collect the values from the iterators in turn:

```
[ it1, it2, it3 ].collectMany { it.collect() }
```

Or as [Dave Newton says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683871/concatenate-iterators-in-groovy#comment29236516_19683871), you could use Guava:

```
@Grab( 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0' )
import com.google.common.collect.Iterators

def it1 = [1, 2].iterator()
def it2 = [3, 4].iterator()
def it3 = [5, 6].iterator()

assert Iterators.concat( it1, it2, it3 ).collect() == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Or commons-collections;

```
@Grab( 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1' )
import org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.IteratorChain

def it1 = [1, 2].iterator()
def it2 = [3, 4].iterator()
def it3 = [5, 6].iterator()

assert new IteratorChain( [ it1, it2, it3 ] ).collect() == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```